# Output received XML data from ajax post to screen

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, cordova

Unfortunately, js and ajax even more so have never been strong points of mine. I have some code that posts via ajax to a site and receives an xml response. I need to do some debugging and need to see the entire xml response to make sure the script is properly parsing the response.

Also and importantly, this is within a mobile app that utilizes some phonegap code so I can't use standard dev tools available in FF,Chrome, etc.

Below is the pertinent code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
timeout:120000,
url: urltxt,
async: true,
data:tdata,
beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("c","Processing...",false);
}, //Show spinner
complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()
}, //Hide spinner


success: function(msg){
error = "";
$(msg).find('response').each(function(){

lots of code to test various responses...
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The question was & is how to output the received xml response to the screen. I also updated the question to make note of the rather important fact that this is part of a mobile app utilizing some phonegap code so I can't use some of the regular dev tools available on desktops.

Answer (score 1):

I find that having [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) open as I'm working the best way to capture and inspect all requests and responses between the browser and the server.  It allows you to inspect the raw traffic, or provide syntax specific filters for XML and JSON, from which you can copy to other editors.  You can also save the session, for later use.

Comment: I should have noted that I need this to be done with code as this is part of a mobile app so the debugging needs to take place within the app due to dependencies. Sorry for not mentioning that initially.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check the response xml is to use Firebug addon in either firefox or chrome (recomend firefox). The addon has a tab called net that will show a tree structure of any ajax request (xml, json, etc). You can google for more details. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: As I noted in response to a few other answers, I should nave mentioned this was part of a mobile app so it needs to be a code based solution that I can add to the script since I'm having to debug it within the actual app. Sorry for failing to mention that initially.